# How can I exclude in my query that rows that have status is Pending and the Creation Date is less than the current date?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

How can I exclude in my query that rows that have status is Pending and the Creation Date is less than the current date ?

```
[Table]  
Status CreationDate  
Pending  9/30/2014 9:00 PM
Completed 9/14/2014 10:52 AM
Pending 9/30/2014 10:00 PM
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is pretty simple SQL.

Comment: Really? Maybe you can help me on this. Basically need to exclude the Pending Status that has below CreationDate on currentdate.

Comment: In other words, the day before the current day, ignoring the time of day?

Comment: Yes... You're correct...

Comment: Answer posted. I can't test it, as sql fiddle does not support sybase and it is many years since I had sybase at my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * FROM tableA 
WHERE status not like 'Pending'
And CreationDate < GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable 
WHERE Status != 'Pending' 
AND DATE(CreationDate) = GETDATE();
```

As you creation date is a timestamp or datetime field, you want to cast this to Date, so you can compare with the value returned by GetDate which returns a date, not datetime. So, this query only includes those records where status is not pending and the creation date is today, which is the opposite of your exclusion statement.

I could not make you a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of this, as SQL Fiddle does not support Sybase.

Note, casting to date is considered [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) in Sybase, which means it will make efficient use of an index on your creationdate field -- which you should have I you have non-trivial table sizes and plan to run this kind of query a lot.