# How can I filter my query where I don't want to show the record that has pending status AND transactionDate is less than the current date?

Tags: sql, sybase

How can I filter my query where I don't want to show the record that has pending **status** AND **transactionDate** is less than the current date? if the status is pending BUT the transaction date is beyond or same as the current date it will show the data

```
Status TransactionDate  
Pending 9/30/2014
Pending 10/1/2014
Completed 9/10/2014
Error 3/2/2014
Pending 9/19/2014
```

I'm getting a negative feedback? WTF?

```
Output should be:
Status TransactionDate
Pending 9/30/2014
Pending 10/1/2014
Completed 9/10/2014
Error 3/2/2014
```

removed the Pending 9/19 because the status is pending and the transaction date is less than the current date.

Comment: `Select Status,TransactionDate from Table1 where status = 'Pending' and transactiondate < getdate()` there you go with this statement, You should better try this on your own and ask question if you face any issues.

Comment: I knew how to filter using that. What I'm asking should met the two conditions. if not met it will show the data.

Comment: @Murtaza, could you check your query, if your query still show the pending status even the date is beyond the current date?... tsk

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112524/how-can-i-exclude-in-my-query-that-rows-that-have-status-is-pending-and-the-crea. If there is some issue with my answer, please say so, but don't repeatedly ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Status,
TransactionDate 
from Table1 
where status <> 'Pending' 
or transactiondate >= getdate()
```

Will only filter out the results where the status is pending AND the trans date is < `getdate`

Comment: I will not get the other Pending Status.

Comment: You will because they will be picked up by the second term `or transactiondate >= getdate()`